# Reading a CSS property involving calc() with JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have an element with the style `min-height: calc(50% + 10px)`. How can I get this calculation (i.e. "calc(50% + 10px)", *not* the current pixel value) with JavaScript? This does what I need in Chrome, but Firefox just gives me the result of the calculation:

```
getComputedStyle(myEle).minHeight
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P37FQ/1/

The reason why I need the exact "calc" string is that I have to temporarily remove the original `min-height` setting in a script, then restore it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution is to instead of saving the CSS value, you can simply set the style to an empty string:

```
myEle.style.minHeight = '';
```

This will remove the style applied with JavaScript and therefore use the next value, which is the style from the stylesheet.

Comment: See, this is why I _always_ include the reason for asking a question. This completely solves my problem, making the actual question redundant :)